# AzureDevops Docker image from TFSVC Code no such file or directory

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

The goal is to push an image to dockerhub, which works great from the Visual Studio "Publish" feature.

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj", "DockerTestWebsiteLinux/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTestWebsiteLinux"
RUN dotnet build "DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTestWebsiteLinux.dll"]
```

which is the default one for a blank ASP.NET Core project generated with VS2019, newest version.

The pipeline YAML looks like this:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: 'docker hub jc'
    dockerFile: DockerTestWebsiteLinux/Dockerfile
```

(Thats the default one that comes up when you click "Docker" as job, i only changed the path to the dockerfile, since its one project out of many in a solution)

He seems to find the Dockerfile just fine, but then exists with

```
Step 6/16 : COPY ["DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj", "DockerTestWebsiteLinux/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder071437444/DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder071437444/DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
```

What do i do wrong?

The Full Log is:

```
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4891643Z ##[section]Starting: Build an image
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4903893Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4904229Z Task         : Docker
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4904567Z Description  : Build, tag, push, or run Docker images, or run a Docker command
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4904871Z Version      : 0.157.2
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4905150Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4905502Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
2020-06-12T11:19:12.4905906Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9134260Z c99ab064-584c-4340-b58e-7a19ca76f6b8 exists true
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9842066Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9842743Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9843349Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9843985Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9844543Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9845090Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9845644Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9846187Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9846740Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9847280Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9847830Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9848370Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9848914Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9849468Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9850017Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9850568Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9851111Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9851662Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9852200Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9852750Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9853292Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9853843Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9854385Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9855199Z (node:3877) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-06-12T11:19:12.9859182Z [command]/usr/bin/docker build -f /home/vsts/work/9/s/DockerTestWebsiteLinux/Dockerfile -t mlatwork:256 /home/vsts/work/9/s/DockerTestWebsiteLinux
2020-06-12T11:19:13.4004892Z Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.78kB
2020-06-12T11:19:13.4005606Z 
2020-06-12T11:19:13.4565372Z Step 1/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6021599Z 3.1-buster-slim: Pulling from dotnet/core/aspnet
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6038540Z 8559a31e96f4: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6044182Z dc08029e21f9: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6044508Z 734d0e250adf: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6044768Z 84249fbd30d6: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6045041Z 84d07bfbfd3f: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6045286Z 84249fbd30d6: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6045529Z 84d07bfbfd3f: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:13.6905803Z 734d0e250adf: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:13.8902364Z dc08029e21f9: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:13.8904333Z dc08029e21f9: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:13.9788197Z 8559a31e96f4: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:13.9793870Z 8559a31e96f4: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:14.0424733Z 84249fbd30d6: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:14.0429176Z 84249fbd30d6: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:14.0836902Z 84d07bfbfd3f: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:14.0846946Z 84d07bfbfd3f: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:15.1361383Z 8559a31e96f4: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:15.7092876Z dc08029e21f9: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:15.8149265Z 734d0e250adf: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:16.5138806Z 84249fbd30d6: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:16.7693218Z 84d07bfbfd3f: Pull complete

2020-06-12T11:19:16.7722239Z Digest: sha256:b5ca2387bc65608bed936c04f40ddd92e8b6a5a3387f38a210e18d531080f2ca
2020-06-12T11:19:16.7751385Z Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim
2020-06-12T11:19:16.7759194Z  ---> 7e3fe71c7693
2020-06-12T11:19:16.7759605Z Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
2020-06-12T11:19:20.0241824Z  ---> Running in 5f40e0c57f8f
2020-06-12T11:19:21.0254992Z Removing intermediate container 5f40e0c57f8f
2020-06-12T11:19:21.0256309Z  ---> 781ae87ed64e
2020-06-12T11:19:21.0256726Z Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
2020-06-12T11:19:21.0753001Z  ---> Running in f63a9f7f81a0
2020-06-12T11:19:22.0301005Z Removing intermediate container f63a9f7f81a0
2020-06-12T11:19:22.0302213Z  ---> 7a89f78b321c
2020-06-12T11:19:22.0302737Z Step 4/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1082117Z 3.1-buster: Pulling from dotnet/core/sdk
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1082686Z e9afc4f90ab0: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1083039Z 989e6b19a265: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1083406Z af14b6c2f878: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1083748Z 5573c4b30949: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1084108Z 17f039feca24: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1084451Z a739c871edc6: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1084919Z 8d7e6a1ea13e: Pulling fs layer
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1085152Z 17f039feca24: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1085370Z a739c871edc6: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1085614Z 8d7e6a1ea13e: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:22.1085832Z 5573c4b30949: Waiting
2020-06-12T11:19:22.2752636Z 989e6b19a265: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:22.2753050Z 989e6b19a265: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:22.2890385Z af14b6c2f878: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:22.2890748Z af14b6c2f878: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:22.4478115Z 17f039feca24: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:22.4478471Z 17f039feca24: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:22.7472123Z e9afc4f90ab0: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:22.7472472Z e9afc4f90ab0: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:22.9057708Z 5573c4b30949: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:22.9059825Z 5573c4b30949: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:23.0119160Z 8d7e6a1ea13e: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:23.0120321Z 8d7e6a1ea13e: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:23.7463177Z a739c871edc6: Verifying Checksum
2020-06-12T11:19:23.7464827Z a739c871edc6: Download complete
2020-06-12T11:19:24.9514807Z e9afc4f90ab0: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:25.2664959Z 989e6b19a265: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:25.5500940Z af14b6c2f878: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:27.5001594Z 5573c4b30949: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:27.8404155Z 17f039feca24: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:31.4556340Z a739c871edc6: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:31.9511844Z 8d7e6a1ea13e: Pull complete
2020-06-12T11:19:31.9534709Z Digest: sha256:1616a64f2eb95e1d9bc0f7185cff16aa44ce0f63c8f61d6bebac5f810d580711
2020-06-12T11:19:31.9550718Z Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
2020-06-12T11:19:31.9558815Z  ---> 5f369f0d8192
2020-06-12T11:19:31.9559092Z Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
2020-06-12T11:19:40.3165947Z  ---> Running in 9d104c6e7d2b
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0594271Z Removing intermediate container 9d104c6e7d2b
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0595329Z  ---> d49cec115c36
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0595671Z Step 6/16 : COPY ["DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj", "DockerTestWebsiteLinux/"]
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0596514Z COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder071437444/DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj: no such file or directory
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0645016Z ##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder071437444/DockerTestWebsiteLinux/DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj: no such file or directory
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0800905Z ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
2020-06-12T11:19:41.0837329Z ##[section]Finishing: Build an image
```

Edit: i made the problem more reproduceable:

1) Create an empty ASP.NET Core project with Docker support
2) Upload that project into an Azure Devops GIT repo
3) create a pipeline, select "Docker build" as a task

the default pipeline looks like this:

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/AzureDevopsDockerTest/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

But it still exists with:

```
Step 7/26 : COPY ["AzureDevopsDockerTest/AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj", "AzureDevopsDockerTest/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder580556181/AzureDevopsDockerTest/AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder580556181/AzureDevopsDockerTest/AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

The dockerfile in this particular case:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AzureDevopsDockerTest/AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj", "AzureDevopsDockerTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AzureDevopsDockerTest/AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AzureDevopsDockerTest"
RUN dotnet build "AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AzureDevopsDockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AzureDevopsDockerTest.dll"]
```

Comment: YAML pipelines don't support TFVC. Are you actually using TFVC, or are you using Git?

Comment: So I clicked "see yaml" on the top right in the editor, does that mean it's the yaml pipeline, or do I still use the classical editor? Would that mean I have to migrate the whole project to git?

Comment: Update: i tried it with a git repo and the actual yaml pipeline. The same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a `buildContext` with the `DockerTestWebsiteLinux.csproj` folder:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: 'docker hub jc'
    dockerFile: DockerTestWebsiteLinux/Dockerfile
    buildContext: DockerTestWebsiteLinux
```

I don't know exactly your folders structure, but - for example, I have the following structure:

```
Dockerfile
.gitignore
--- TestVars
    - TestVars.sln
    - TestVars
       - TestVars.csprog
       - Program.cs
```

If I do not provide a context the build failed with `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder275111569/TestVars/TestVars.csproj: no such file or directory`.

But, if I give the context: `buildContext: TestVars` the build is succeded:

```
Step 3/5 : COPY ["TestVars/TestVars.csproj", "TestVars/"]
 ---> c9f02a6cd4b0
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way *(that worked for me too)* is to avoid any hardcoding and use the context like the following example:

```
buildContext: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Cool, works for me as well. This stage in azure pipeline could be more intelligent

Comment: Worked fine for me too and I agree, Azure Pipeline should definitely be more intelligent

Answer (score 5):

Okay so far i was able to find out a "solution". It seems like the DevOps Team and the Visual Studio Team from Microsoft did not have a meeting to sync the out-of-the-box configs. I am now using 2 different dockerfiles, one for deploying from within visual studio (manually upload) and one for DevOps builds.

The visual studio one is the default one that comes with a new "docker support" project. The one working in devops is this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTestWebsiteLinux.dll"]
```

This does not work in Visual Studio (nor building or deploying).

Maybe there is a way to make one dockerfile that works in both, but i am not deep enough into dockerfiles to do that.