# How can I solve COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I got stuck very interesting issue with azure pipeline. The issue is "Forbidden path outside the build context".If you have an add line in the Dockerfile which points to another directory, the build of the image fails with the message "Forbidden path".How can I solve this?

I was recently attempting to Dockerize a C# project, so I added a docker folder to the project and created a simple Dockerfile to get started like below:

Error:

```
f83e9c616794: Pulling fs layer
9887694812e5: Pulling fs layer
9887694812e5: Verifying Checksum
9887694812e5: Download complete
dd4da9d953fb: Verifying Checksum
dd4da9d953fb: Download complete
f83e9c616794: Verifying Checksum
f83e9c616794: Download complete
dd4da9d953fb: Pull complete
f83e9c616794: Pull complete
9887694812e5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:85ea9832ae26c70618418cf7c699186776ad066d88770fd6fd1edea9b260379a
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
 ---> bd73c72c93a1
Step 5/25 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in b457b1934a7e
Removing intermediate container b457b1934a7e
 ---> a50c5df6f929
Step 6/25 : COPY ["./src/xxxxx.Web/xxxxx.Web.csproj", "src/xxxxx.Web/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/xxxxx.Web/xxxxx.Web.csproj: file does not exist
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/xxxxx.Web/xxxxx.Web.csproj: file does not exist
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build and push an image to container registry
```

DockerFiles/Dockerfile.xxxxx.Web:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/xxxxx.Web/xxxxx.Web.csproj", "src/xxxxx.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/xxxxx.Web/xxxxx.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/xxxxx.Web"
RUN dotnet build "xxxxx.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "xxxxx.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xxxxx.Web.dll"]
```

azure-pipeline.yml:

```
 # Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# Build and push image to Azure Container Registry; Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- test


variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  imageRepository: 'xxxxxxxx'
  containerRegistry: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/DockerFiles/Dockerfile.xxxxx.Web'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - publish: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy-xxxxx.Web
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'xxxxx-5982.default'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:


          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.eventhub.web.yml
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.eventhub.web.yml
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

How can I solve "COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context"? **I want to use Dockerfile in DockerFiles Directory.**

Comment: You can try to add `buildContext` in the Docker task. Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343444/azuredevops-docker-image-from-tfsvc-code-no-such-file-or-directory/62377288#62377288).

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer. I will check it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to add `buildContext` parameter in the Docker task.

[buildContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs): Path to the build context

Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343444/azuredevops-docker-image-from-tfsvc-code-no-such-file-or-directory/62377288#62377288) you can refer to.

Comment: Something like this: buildContext: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)

Comment: Could be: `buildContext: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` if the file that has to be copied is downloaded to there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Build Context, uncheck the Use Default Build Context and set the Project Solution folder.
Refer image
[image: build context set]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer if **Dockerfile** happens to be inside for. ex the Web Api project or similar(what usually Visual Studio generated) just uncheck the *'Use Default Build Context'* and leave the input empty.
Worked for me.