# Azure Devops Pipeline - file not found in build context

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Getting an error in the Azure DevOps Pipeline:

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["demo6/demo6.csproj", "demo6/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat demo6/demo6.csproj: file does not exist
```

NOTES-run the pipeline in diagnostics mode and the .sln file exists

```
##[debug]cwd=/home/vsts/work/1/s
##[debug]  /home/vsts/work/1/s/demo6.sln (file)
##[debug]  /home/vsts/work/1/s/demo6/demo6.csproj (file)
```

I have a multi-project Asp.Net Core solution with the folder structure and projects as follows:

```
demo6
 |--demo6/demo6.csproj
 |--demo6.api/demo6.api.csproj
```

The app is demo6 which references demo6.api which is a class library.

This is in GitHub in a repository demo6. I modified the autogenerated Dockerfile to add the extra demo6/ to see if that works but no.

Appreciate any help.

Dockerfile below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["demo6/demo6.csproj", "demo6/"]
RUN dotnet restore "demo6/demo6.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/demo6"
RUN dotnet build "demo6.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "demo6.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "demo6.dll"]
```

Also tried this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["demo6/demo6/demo6.csproj", "ddemo6/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ddemo6/demo6.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ddemo6"
RUN dotnet build "demo6.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "demo6.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "demo6.dll"]
```

Got this error:

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["demo6/demo6/demo6.csproj", "ddemo6/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat demo6/demo6/demo6.csproj: file does not exist
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat demo6/demo6/demo6.csproj: file does not exist
```

here's the repo structure[image]

Comment: Does the docker build run properly when testing locally?

Comment: The way you have your file tree written, from the root, the path would be `demo6/demo6/demo6.csproj`

Comment: yes it worked after that i put it on github, created the pipeline

Comment: @khuynh, yes i tried that too and it didn't work

Comment: Hi @Kumar, based on the error message, it seems that cannot found the file on the path `demo6/demo6.csproj`, could you share a screenshot of the repo structure here? Thanks.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT it looks like a bug, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362487/bug-in-azure-devops-pipeline-vs-templates-dockerfile,  i created another post as i did not want to delete/update the post and the responses to this one, if it's confirmed then will delete this or link from here

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT added the screenshot

Comment: have you checked `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @Tirex yes, also checked the logs in azure and all the files are present

Answer (score 4):

The reason of *file not found* error may be the relative path of the `Dockerfile` and the `csproj` are different. Try to set the `Dockerfile` in the root of the solution should solve your error.

Also you need to add a `buildContext` with the `csproj` folder.

[buildContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs): Path to the build context

Also, here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343444/azuredevops-docker-image-from-tfsvc-code-no-such-file-or-directory/62377288#62377288) you can refer to.

One more possible cause of COPY failed: no source files were specified is .dockerignore file present in your workspace

Look for `.dockerignore` file because of docker’s CLI (command line interface) it sends context to the docker daemon to load the .dockerignore file.

If the `.dockerignore` file exist in the context than it might be possible there is exclude entry to ignore the build directory

```
# ignore or exclude build directory
*/build*
*/*/build*
```

Comment: Based on this answer, I fixed my problem by unchecking "Use Default Build Context" in the Docker build task (Classic pipeline).  For YAML, I believe the equivalent is defaultContext: false. I left "Build Context" blank, which set the context to the root solution folder as the Dockerfile expected.